# Can a cell value trigger a userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a small billing system in Excel for a Dental Office (Just mentioning it in case someone has any tips/tricks/suggestions on cool ideas not really related to the issue i'm facing). I have a small template for creating invoices in one of the cells I have a data validation for selecting the patient, I was wondering if in the list the name selected is "New Patient" a UserForm can pop up to input the new patient information?

Comment: See [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eg: put this in the worksheet module and adjust references as appropriate

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const NEW_PAT As String = "New Patient"
    Const RNG_NEW_PAT As String = "B3"
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Target.Cells(1) 'in case multiple cells changed...

    If c.Address = Me.Range(RNG_NEW_PAT).Address Then
        If c.Value = NEW_PAT Then
            'show userform
        End If
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: If I have the userform in a different workbook can it be called? I do have in a different Workbook a Userform to register the new patients. Now you may be asking yourself well if said workbook exist why you want to call it in the billing workbook, in case someone just walks in really quick for an emergency and don have time to fill it. Ideally in such situations what it would happen is I would open the billing system select new the patient registration form would appear and save the information in the patient registration form and then I can go back to the billing and select the patient.